# What is the "current actor" in the Swift Concurrency model?

Tags: swift, concurrency, actor

Reading the [Concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/3856791-init) section of the Swift Guide, I came across:

> To create an unstructured task that runs on the current actor, call the `Task.init(priority:operation:)` initializer. To create an unstructured task that’s not part of the current actor, known more specifically as a detached task, call the `Task.detached(priority:operation:)` class method.

There is the phrase "current actor". This is also mentioned in the documentation of [`Task.init`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/3856791-init):

> Runs the given nonthrowing operation asynchronously as part of a new top-level task on behalf of the current actor.

Before, I thought I had understood what "current actor" meant:

- if the code runs on the main queue, then the current actor can be thought of as the `MainActor`, since its executor is the main queue.
- if the code is marked with a global actor attribute, then its current actor is that global actor
- if the code is in an `actor` and is not `nonisolated`, then its current actor is that actor.

```
@SomeOtherActor
func somethingElse() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // current actor is MainActor
    }
}

@MainActor
class Foo: NSObject {
    func foo() { /* current actor is MainActor */ }
}

actor Bar {
    func foo() { /* current actor is Bar */ }
}
```

However, recently I realised that I forgot to consider a situation - what happens on a global queue (or any other random queue)?

```
@SomeOtherActor
func somethingElse() {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        // current actor is?
    }
}
```

When I tried accessing one of the actor-isolated properties of `SomeOtherActor` in the closure, I get the message:

> Property 'x' isolated to global actor 'SomeOtherActor' can not be mutated from a non-isolated context

Is that Swift's way of saying there is no current actor? If so, what will `Task.init` do? The documentation doesn't really say.

Ideally, is there a way to programmatically print the current actor?

I thought the SE proposals would explain what "current actor" meansNone of the SE proposals mention the word "current actor": [SE-0306](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0306-actors.md), [SE-0313](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0313-actor-isolation-control.md), [SE-0316](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0316-global-actors.md#global-actor-function-types), [SE-0327](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0327-actor-initializers.md), [SE-0344](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0344-distributed-actor-runtime.md).

Comment: You should use `Task.detached` instead of `DispatchQueue.global().async`

Comment: Good question! I’ve been following it for a while to learn from the answer, but I’m saddened to see there isn’t any yet. Have you considered posting this question on the Swift forums? It’ll certainly get a lot of love there

Comment: @Alexander I'm too lazy to create an account there :P Between when I posted this and now, I started wondering whether mixing dispatch queues and actors is something that you are *supposed* to do in the first place, as I've heard lots of things about "don't use Swift concurrency with X". If we are not supposed to do that then the question is kind of moot isn't it? You can post this on Swift Forums if you want! :)

Comment: It’s a great community, I totally recommend it! Especially given how active and informative you are around here

Comment: i proxied this question to the swift forums (here: https://forums.swift.org/t/current-actor-semantics-question/60120), and some useful clarifications were provided. namely, in the DispatchQueue scenario there is no 'current actor'.

Comment: I think an important here is that there isn't always a current actor (i.e. when not in an async context at all), right?

Comment: @fruitcoder - Correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you have resolved your question by now, but for the sake of future readers, let me provide an answer.

You suggested:

> if the code runs on the main queue, then the current actor can be thought of as the `MainActor`, since its executor is the main queue.

Not necessarily so. Just because something runs on the main queue (or main thread) doesn’t mean it is isolated to the main actor. Now, `UIViewController`, SwiftUI `body`, and the like are isolated to the main actor, so, as a result, much stuff we initiate from the UI is automatically actor-isolated. But you can easily introduce a non-isolated function (either one that is explicitly marked as `nonisolated` or a random method in a non-isolated type or a non-isolated closure) into the process.

Let’s consider a few of your examples. First:

```swift
@SomeOtherActor
func somethingElse() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // is this isolated to the main actor?
    }
}
```

It appears that there is some compiler optimization (in Swift 5.9, at least) by which the compiler can successfully infer that this is on the main actor (despite the lack of any `@MainActor` qualifier). But consider the following:

```swift
@SomeOtherActor
func somethingElse() {
    let queue: DispatchQueue = .main
    queue.async {
        self.baz()     // some stuff isolated to the main actor
        self.qux = 1
    }
}
```

That looks very similar, but the compiler is no longer able to infer that you are isolated to the main actor (at this point, at least). Anyway, you may now receive a warning:

> Call to main actor-isolated instance method 'baz()' in a synchronous nonisolated context; this is an error in Swift 6

(You may need to set the “Strict Concurrency Checking” build setting to “Complete”.)

[image]

The bottom line, just because you are on the main queue/thread does *not* ensure that you are isolated to the main actor. When this happens, if the methods/properties you call *are* isolated to the main actor, the compiler infer misuse (with “Strict Concurrency Checking” build setting, at least), and warn you as such.

Now, I admit that my above example of `queue.async {…}` is a bit contrived. But there are lots of examples where you can accidentally introduce non-isolated contexts (e.g., some helper class that is not actor-isolated, some legacy `@preconcurrency` contexts/callbacks, etc.), where this general caveat of “just because I may be on the main thread, it doesn’t mean I’m isolated to the main actor” applies. But if you ensure your types, methods, and properties are correctly isolated, then the compiler will take care of it from there, without any additional decoration required at the call point.

---

Now, given that we should (with a few exceptions) retire GCD API during the transition to Swift concurrency, if you want it on the main actor, you theoretically could isolate a `Task` to the main actor:

```swift
@SomeOtherActor
func somethingElse() {
    Task { @MainActor in
        // current actor is MainActor
    }
}
```

But that is a very GCD-way of thinking of the logic (placing the burden on the caller to ensure stuff is run on the main actor). It also unnecessarily introduces [unstructured concurrency](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/concurrency#Unstructured-Concurrency).

It is generally better to mark stuff that needs to run on the main actor as such, and just call it (with compile-time verification of code correctness):

```swift
@SomeOtherActor
func somethingElse() async {
    …
    await somethingThatRequiresMainActor()
    …
}

@MainActor
func somethingThatRequiresMainActor() {
    …
}
```

The idea is that we should simply isolate methods that need to run on the particular actor as such (or, a little cleaner, put them inside a type that is isolated to the appropriate actor; that way you don't have to decorate all the actor-isolated methods individually) and let the compiler check for code-correctness. That way, we enjoy compile-time verification of our code rather than relying on manual runtime checks.

FWIW, this evolution from GCD to `Task { @MainActor in … }` to actor-isolated methods and properties is illustrated in WWDC 2021’s [Swift concurrency: Update a sample app](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10194/).

---

You then asked:

> However, recently I realised that I forgot to consider a situation - what happens on a global queue (or any other random queue)?
>
> ```swift
> @SomeOtherActor
> func somethingElse() {
>     DispatchQueue.global().async {
>         // current actor is?
>     }
> }
> ```

It probably goes without saying at this point, but the dispatch to the global queue is not isolated to any actor.

Nowadays, you would either replace that dispatch to the global queue with a `Task.detached {…}` or, as of Swift 5.7 (as a result of [SE-0338](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0338-clarify-execution-non-actor-async.md)), you can just have a nonisolated `async` function to get that off the current actor, if that is your intent. E.g.:

```swift
@SomeOtherActor
func somethingElse() async {
    await somethingThatDoesNotRequireActorIsolation()
}

nonisolated func somethingThatDoesNotRequireActorIsolation() async {
    …
}
```